# How to export device specific C++ project from Xilinx SDK to other IDE?

Tags: javascript, c++, xilinx

I have a C++ project in my Xilinx SDK which is target specific. It includes some board support package (BSP) and therefore can only be compiled in the XSDK.

I need to use this project from my new JavaScript project to get some data, but I've never done this before. Is this possible, and how?

Comment: AFAIK the main way to call into C++ from JavaScript is via node.js, but I haven't yet had an opportunity to use it.

Comment: This question is going to get flagged by moderators, as the nature of the question is to broad for StackOverflow, you should probably look to a more forum-style site for this kind of open question, like Reddit.

Comment: @Tzalumen well, it's for client rather than server, and the board is not so powerful, so node.js is not a good choice I think. I'm not familiar with node.js, plz correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I wish I was more familiar with node.js, I just know it's presently a very popular way to integrate C/C++ binaries and JavaScript. Your main power hog is going to be JavaScript and the JavaScript interpreter. If that is running on another machine, you might want to use some form of inter-process communication to send messages between your C++ application and your JavaScript application.

Comment: Thanks @Tzalumen , that's the most popular way and may be the best. Since I have only a few message to communicate, so I use websocket for a light-weight task, it went well.